# Cannot set property '_onButtonClick' of null with Polymer Neon Animations

Tags: javascript, polymer

I'm pretty new to Polymer and JS, but I've been trying to get used to both. Using [this demo](http://morethanreal.github.io/neon-animation-demo/bower_components/neon-animation/demo/doc/basic.html) as a base, I've been trying to attach a scale-down animation to some icons using Neon Animations and a button click event. Whenever I try to use querySelector to find the template containing the button, it always returns:

```
"icon-toggle-demo.html:34 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_onButtonClick' of null"
```

No matter what I change I just can't get the button to not be null. I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

My file containing the button:

```
<link rel="import" href="../../polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="../icon-toggle.html">


<dom-module id="icon-toggle-demo">
    <template is="dom-bind">
        <style>
            :host {
                font-family: sans-serif;
            }

            ;
        </style>

        <h3>Statically-configured icon-toggles</h3>
        <button on-click="_onButtonClick">click me</button>
        <icon-toggle toggle-icon="star"></icon-toggle>
        <icon-toggle toggle-icon="star" pressed></icon-toggle>

        <h3>Data-bound icon-toggle</h3>

        <!-- use a computed binding to generate the message -->
        <div><span>[[message(isFav)]]</span></div>


        <!-- curly brackets ({{}}} allow two-way binding -->
        <icon-toggle toggle-icon="favorite" pressed="{{isFav}}"></icon-toggle>
    </template>

    <script>
        var scope = document.querySelector('template[is="dom-bind"]');

        scope._onButtonClick = function(event) {
            var node = document.querySelector('toggle-icon');
            if (node) {
                node.animate();
            }
        };
    </script>

</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [`dom-bind` templates](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/api/dom-bind) are only needed in `index.html`. In a `<dom-module>`, you can just use a plain `<template>`.
- To [register your element](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements), you'll need to use the `Polymer` function with a prototype object that has your `_onButtonClick` function like this:

  ```
  Polymer({
    is: 'icon-toggle-demo',
    _onButtonClick: function() {
      ...
    }
  });
  ```
- [Auto-node finding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom#node-finding) allows you to quickly access a node by ID with `this.$.NODE_ID` (e.g., `this.$.myIcon`). So, if your `<icon-toggle>` had an ID of "starIcon":

  ...you could access it from your Polymer object with `this.$.starIcon`:

  ```
  _onButtonClick: function() {
    this.$.starIcon.animate();
  }
  ```

Your full element definition would look something like this:

```
<dom-module id="icon-toggle-demo">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        font-family: sans-serif;
      }
    </style>

    <h3>Statically-configured icon-toggles</h3>
    <button on-click="_onButtonClick">click me</button>
    <icon-toggle id="starIcon" toggle-icon="star"></icon-toggle>
    <icon-toggle toggle-icon="star" pressed></icon-toggle>

    <h3>Data-bound icon-toggle</h3>

    <!-- use a computed binding to generate the message -->
    <div><span>[[message(isFav)]]</span></div>

    <!-- curly brackets ({{}}} allow two-way binding -->
    <icon-toggle toggle-icon="favorite" pressed="{{isFav}}"></icon-toggle>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'icon-toggle-demo',
      _onButtonClick: function() {
        this.$.starIcon.animate();
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: Thank you! This was very important in learning how all this works. Wasn't sure about the dom-bind until now!

Comment: @Taylor No problem :)